# Delete odd-numbers in a list C

Tags: c, list, struct

I need help for list and nodes in C. I defined them as struct as follow in a .h file:

```
typedef struct node{

     int value;
     struct node*prox;

 }node;

 typedef Nodo *list;
```

I can't understand why the function to delete all odd numbers is not working. The program is just crashing. Where am I doing wrong?

```
list delete_odd_numbers(list l){

   node*temp;
   node*current;
   node*prev;

   if(l->value%2!=0){         

        temp=l;
    l=l->prox;
    free(temp);

   }else{

       prev=NULL;
       current=l;
       while(current!=NULL){

           if(current!=NULL &&current->value%2!=0){

               temp=current;
               prev->prox=current->prox;
               free(temp);

           }else{

           prev=current;
           current=current->prox;

           }
       }

   }
   return l;

}
```

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger (gdb or lldb, probably)? It can help you find the actual line that it is crashing on.

Answer (score 0):

do you know how to use a debugger and step through the code while looking at the values of the variables?  In any case, in the large "else" statement, you are initializing prev=NULL, and then further down, you are referencing prev->prox  -- so you are dereferencing a null pointer